# Find the sum of digits of a sequence of integers

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, sum, digits

I made up my mind to write a little piece of code that gets two integers, lets say M and N ( M <= N ) and sum the digits of all the integers between them, inclusive. So for example if M = 1 and N = 9, DigitSum will equal to 45. If M = 10 and N = 11 the sum will be (1 + 0 (10) + 1 + 1 (11) = 3).
Here is my code so far (Done the for loop instead of the return):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
// the partial digits sums digitSum[i] = the sum of the digits between 0 and i
int digitSum[] = {0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45};
int pow_of_ten[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000};
 // the sums of all the digits in the numbers from 1 to (10^(i) - 1) where i is the index in the array
long subsums[] = {0, 45, 20 * 45, 300 * 45, 4000 * 45, 50000 * 45, 600000 * 45, 7000000 * 45, 80000000 * 45,
    900000000 * 45};
//Calculates the sum of all digits between 0 and M inclusive
long Digit_Sum(int M) {

  if (M < 10) {
    return digitSum[M];
  }
  long result = 0;
  int same = M;
  int counter = 0;
  int lastdigit = 0;
  while (same > 0) {
    if (same <  10) {
      lastdigit = same;
      break;
    }
    same /= 10;
    counter ++;
  }
  for(;counter >= 0; counter --) {
    result += (subsums[counter] + M % pow_of_ten[counter] + 1) * lastdigit;
    result += digitSum[lastdigit - 1] * pow_of_ten[counter];
    if (counter == 0) {
      break;
    }
    lastdigit = (M / pow_of_ten[counter - 1]) % 10;
  }
  return result;

}

int main() {

int M;
int N;
vector<long> sums;
while (true) {
  cin >> M >> N;
  if (M == 0 &&  N == 0) {
    break;
  }
  sums.push_back(Digit_Sum(N) - Digit_Sum(M - 1));
}

for (vector<long>::iterator it = sums.begin(); it != sums.end(); ++it) {
  cout << *it << endl;
}
}
```

For most cases this works well but an Online judge says it is wrong. I looked at other solutions that work but no one hard-coded the values in arrays the way I did. May this cause a partial problem, any ideas?

Comment: You could perform this logic with a one line loop, why all the added complexity?

Comment: You could perform this logic with a *single simple expression*, just calculate it. Hint: if you think about computing twice the sum, then it can be viewed as the sum of one sequence of values plus the reverse sequence.

Comment: Are you not allowed the simple formula, `M*(M+1)/2`?

Comment: @RSahu Sahu How can I use this form to calculate _the digits_ of a sequence.

Comment: Why are you using an array of powers of 10?  Try dividing by 10 to shift the digits right and modulo (%) to get the value of the right most digit.

Comment: Where's your *design*?  You could have a problem in your concept, or in its implementation.  Properly documenting the concept will help determine which of those is the issue (also, the process may reveal the error to you -- that's called *rubber duck debugging* and the Stack Overflow designers were big fans)

Comment: What I mean is that clearly you've done much more thinking about the problem that either of the two answerers so far, and found patterns that they haven't even thought to look for.  But you need to share that thinking with us in order for us to troubleshoot.  Expecting us to reverse-engineer the design from the code is crazy, and designing a solution from scratch is also an excessive amount of work to ask for here.

Comment: What are the online judge's input constraints? Could you be overflowing `int`?

Comment: @BenVoigt I tried to explain a little bit more now. Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: @aschepler  Yes, `result` was `long` -  fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just create a for-loop to greatly simplify this code.

There is no need to go through all that effort.

```
for (Initialization Action, Boolean Expression, Update_Action)
```

Comment: Which part may be transformed and be both simple and fast using a for loop.  What kind of mistake is involved here that I can not see. Yes I can delete the recursion and make a loop, is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't see any mistakes, I just said you can greatly simplify this code using a for -loop.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Re deletion below: sorry, I have a bit influenza and mizread `N` as `M`. :(</sup>

<del>I think a main error is `M-1` in</del>

<del>`sums.push_back(Digit_Sum(N) - Digit_Sum(M - 1));`</del>

<del>Also noting that <*when corrected*  that formula will only work for single-digit numbers</del>. My comment earlier about using a simple formula was based on misunderstanding your problem description, in view of that formula and your examples. Both indicated single digit numbers only.

However, the complexity of the code appears unreasonably high. Consider this, assuming non-negative integers as input, and assuming `m` is always less than or equal to `n`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

bool throwX() { throw std::runtime_error( "Ouch." ); }

auto main() -> int
{
    for( ;; )
    {
        int m, n;
        cin >> m >> n || throwX();
        if( m == 0 && n == 0 ) { break; }

        int sum = 0;
        for( int i = m; i <= n; ++i )
        {
            for( int v = i; v != 0; v /= 10 )
            {
                sum += v % 10;
            }
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
}
```

It needs not be more complicated than that.

Comment: Unless you want complexity better than `O((N-M) lg N)`, in which case a smarter approach will be needed.

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes. and the difference formula could work for a smarter approach, but then `Digit_sum` is a bit misleadingly named (it would have to compute the sum of digits for all numbers up to and including argument). still the code for that isn't much more complicated.

Comment: Sorry all I have a bit of influenza and misread `N` as `M`. :( Fixing.

Comment: Yes @Cheersandhth.-Alf this approach will work perfectly well, although it won't fit the time constraint of 1 second.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, can you elaborate on inner two nested forloops?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm not sure this code works. `1 9` returns `45`, `1 10` returns `46`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working to spec, sans console input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void sum_a_to_b(const int & a, const int & b)
{
    if (a <= b && a >= 0)
    {
        long long sum = 0;
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
        cout << "Sum of digits from " << a << " through " << b << " is " << sum << ".\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    sum_a_to_b(5, 6);
    sum_a_to_b(1, 9);
}
```

Comment: This computes the sum of the numbers, not the sum of their (decimal representation) digits.

Comment: We are seeking the sum of the decimal digits of all the numbers in the sequence. Will change the example on top.